# Gstreamer Camera to HLS optimization

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, http-live-streaming

I have a following Gstreamer pipeline (which generated HLS and a separate MP4 file).
Is there anything I can do to optimize it in terms of CPU / memory / delay?

```
gst-launch-1.0 \
       v4l2src name=video_source \
       ! videorate \
       ! 'video/x-raw,format=YUY2,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080' \
       ! nvvidconv \
       ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=NV12' \
       ! omxh264enc \
           bitrate=30000 \
           profile=8 \
           preset-level=3 \
       ! tee \
           name=t \
       t. \
         ! queue \
         ! h264parse name=pre_stream\
         ! hlssink2 \
             playlist-length=0 \
             max-files=50000 \
             target-duration=3 \
             location='segment%05d.ts' \
             playlist-location='playlist.m3u8' \
       t. \
         ! queue \
         ! h264parse name=pre_mpeg\
         ! mp4mux fragment-duration=1 \
         ! filesink \
             append=true \
             location='video.mp4'
```